# How to send a POST request as form-data when FormData is unavailable? (Airtable scripts)

Tags: javascript, multipartform-data, form-data, cloudinary, airtable

The Cloudinary API requires to send data using `multipart/form-data`, but I'm working in an environment where FormData [is not available](https://airtable.com/developers/scripting/api/fetch#differences-from-fetch-in-the-browser).

How could I do something as simple as this, then?

```
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('file', assetUrl);
  formData.append('upload_preset', CLOUDINARY_UNSIGNED_UPLOAD_PRESET);
  formData.append('cloud_name', CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_NAME);

     console.debug(`Uploading file (id: ${id}) to Cloudinary`, CLOUDINARY_UPLOAD_URL, formData);
      const response = await fetch(CLOUDINARY_UPLOAD_URL, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData,
      });
```

I tried different approaches, but it seems the Cloudinary API is really sensitive about it, and doesn't allow sending data in any other format other than `multipart/form-data`.

Comment: According to that page the browser-native Fetch is only available in the scripting extension - but not in the scripting automation action. So your best bet is to use a proxy - send the file as Base64 encoded value to your proxy which in turn will make the FormData request to Cloudinary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloudinary API supports not only `multipart/form-data`, but also `JSON` and `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

If you're sending a string as the value of the `file` parameter, such as a remote URL (in your case) or Base64, then you can use any of the above-mentioned Content-Types.

For example, you could try the following example which will successfully upload the image into a cloud (you'll want to replace `<your-cloud>`, `<file-url>` and `<upload-preset>` with your actual values):

```
fetch('https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/<your-cloud>/image/upload', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers:{
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    },    
    body: new URLSearchParams({
        'file': '<file-url>',
        'upload_preset': '<upload-preset>'
    })
});
```

Note that the `cloud_name` is derived from the URL you're sending the data to therefore it should not be sent in your request `body`.

Comment: Indeed, this worked well! I had tried to use JSON.stringify, instead of URLSearchParams, which is what I usually use when sending data to an API. Not so obvious to understand why one works while the other fail

Comment: @Vadorequest - Great to hear it worked. In regards to JSON Stringify, the output of that is not compatible with the Content-Type being set at the same time (application/x-www-form-urlencoded'). JSON stringify will work too in the above example but you will want to change the Content-Type to "application/json".